# Expected value, from characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I have a random variable, $Z$ with a its characteristic function given as $\varphi_Z(x)=e^{-|x|}, x\in \mathbb{R}$. How do I calculate $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]$?

- I do not have the assumption that $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]<\infty$, so I cannot use that $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\frac{1}{i}\varphi_Z(0)$, thus I am stuck.

Comment: Are you saying that if $\mathbb{E}[Z] \not = \frac{1}{i}\varphi_Z(0)$, then $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\infty$? Because in my book it doesnt go "both" ways.

Comment: If the $E[Z]$ exists, then $\phi_Z(t)$ is differentiable. Since $e^{-|t|}$ is not differentiable (at $t=0$) then $E[Z]$ doesn't exist. It follows that $E[|Z|]$ can't exist either. Therefore, $E[|Z|]=\infty$.

Comment: $Z$ can be shown to be a _Cauchy_ random variable for which $E[Z]$ is undefined (because $E[|Z|]$ is not finite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of a Cauchy distributed random variable with parameters $\gamma=1,x_0=0$ is $$\frac1{\pi(1+x^2)}.$$

Then the pdf of $|X|$ is $$\frac2{\pi(1+x^2)}\text{ if }x\geq 0.$$

The corresponding expectation (times $\frac{\pi}2$) is

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac x{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac x{1+x^2}\ dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac x{1+x^2}\ dx>$$$$>\int_1^{\infty}\frac x{x^2+x^2}\ dx=\frac12\int_1^{\infty}\frac1x\ dx=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what zoli's answer requires (that $\varphi_Z$ is the characteristic function of a standard cauchy distribution):

If for $n \in \Bbb N$ it holds $$E[|Z|^n]< \infty$$ then $\varphi_Z$ is $n$-times continuously differentiable in $0$.

Because your given characteristic function is not differentiable in 0 it cannot hold $$E[|Z|]< \infty$$ hence $$E[|Z|^n]= \infty$$